# How to return to a switch statement with a new variable through a OnClick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building an intake application for clubs. I'm having trouble getting the user from one page to another. Each page is a module, usually a form. And they can differ in position, as in the user can change the position a page has in the intake.

Here's how my database looks like approximately. A club can have 1 or more intakes. An intake consists of multiple modules. The database models look like this:

```
table: intake               
intake_id(P)   club_id
       12345     99999
       12346     99999
       12347     99998

table: intake_has_module
intake_id(P)   module_id   position
       12345           1          2
       12345           2          1
       12345           3          3
       12346           1          1
       12346           2          2
etc.

table: module
module_id(P)                   name
           1   Personal Information
           2   Terms and Conditions
           3          Subscriptions

(Dummy data)
```

Here I get the intake_id from the corresponding club

```
$intake_sql = $db->sql_query('SELECT intake_id FROM fit_vg_intake WHERE club_id = ' . (int)User::currentUser()->getClubID());
$intake_sql_2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($intake_sql);
```

Here I get the module_id that's in first position from the club's intake

```
$module_sql = $db->sql_query('SELECT module_id FROM fit_vg_intake_has_module WHERE position = 1 AND intake_id = ' . $intake_sql_2['intake_id']);
$module_sql_2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($module_sql);
```

Then I use this module_id in a switch that looks like this:

```
switch ($module_sql_2['module_id']) {
case 1:
    generate_page('intake/personalinformation.twig');
    break;
case 2:
    generate_page('intake/termsandconditions.twig');
    break;
case 3:
    generate_page('intake/subscriptions.twig');
    break;
default:
    generate_page('intake/main.twig');
    break;
}
```

So this part is working correctly for me. The user can switch the position of each module in a settings panel.
Now for my problem & question:

Say a user is on the Terms and Conditions module. Which is module_id 2 and position 1. When he clicks a button which confirms that he has accepted the terms and conditions he should be moved to the module that has the position+1 of module_id=2.

What I've tried:
I've tried adding an onClick to the button. When clicked on a javascript function gets called named next_module() with an action called accepted-terms.
I pass this action to the php file in which I use another switch:

```
switch ($action) {
case 'accepted-terms':
    $position_sql = $db->sql_query('SELECT position FROM intake_has_module WHERE module_id = 2 AND intake_id = ' . $intake_sql_2['intake_id']);
    $position_sql_2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($position_sql);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

In this switch as you can see I get the position of the module with module_id=2.
It returns 1 which is correct. Now I can get the module_id with a position of 1+1. This is how far I've come. Basically my question is: How do I return to the first switch with the new module_id when someone clicks a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the handler array and adding the position to the back of the url like /intake/1 , /intake/2 etc

```
$handler_page = System::getHandlerArray()[0];
if($handler_page == null){
$handler_page = '1';
}
```

Here I check if the user is at /intake. If he is and thus System::getHandlerArray()[0] == 0,
I assign 1, for the first position, to the variable.

Then to use this variable in my template I do this:

```
$template->assign_var('position', (int)$handler_page + 1);
```

I add 1 because I want to assign the current position + 1 to this variable because I will be using it to direct the page with an onClick to the next position as is seen here:

```
<script>
function next_module() {
    window.location.href = ('/intake/' + {{ position }});
}
</script>
```